# NodeJS - Response stream

Tags: node.js, sockets, sails.js, rxjs

I built a simple API endpoint with NodeJS using Sails.js.

When someone access my API endpoint, the server starts to wait for data and whenever a new data appears, he broadcasts it using sockets. Each client should receive his own stream of data based on his user input.

```
var Cap = require('cap').Cap;

collect: function (req, res) {

var iface = req.param("ip");

var c = new Cap(),
device = Cap.findDevice(ip);

    c.on('data', function(myData) {
        sails.sockets.blast('message', {"host": myData});
    });
});
```

The response do not complete (I never send a res.json() - what actually happens is that the browser keep loading - but the above functionality works).

2 Problems:

- I'm trying to subscribe and unsubscribe to to this API endpoint from my client (using RxJS). When I subscribe, I start to receive data via sockets - but I can't unsubscribe to the API endpoint (the browser expect the request to be completed).
- Each client should subscribe to his own socket room based on the request IP parameter ( see updated code ). Currently it blasts the message to everyone.

How I can create a stream/service-like API endpoint with Sails.js that will emit new data to each user based on his input?

My goal is to be able to subscribe / unsubscribe to this API endpoint from each client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Revised Answer

Let's assume your API endpoint is defined in `config/routes.js` like this:

```
...
'get     /collect': 'SomeController.collectSubscribe',
'delete  /collect': 'SomeController.collectUnsubscribe',
```

Since each `Cap` instance is tied to one device, we need one instance for each subscription. Instead of using the sails `join`/`leave` methods, we keep track of `Cap` instances in memory and just `broadcast` to the request socket's id. This works because Sails sockets are subscribed to their own ids by default.

In `api/controllers/SomeController.js`:

```
// In order for the `Cap` instances to persist after `collectSubscribe` finishes, we store them all in an Object, associated with which socket the were created for.
var caps = {/* req.socket.id: <instance of Cap>, */};

module.exports = {

...

  collectSubscribe: function(req, res) {
    if (!res.isSocket) return res.badRequest("I need a websocket! Help!");
    if (!!caps[req.socket.id]) return res.badRequest("Dude, you are already subscribed.");

    caps[req.socket.id] = new Cap();
    var c = caps[req.socket.id]; // remember that `c` is a reference to our new `Cap`, not a copy.
    var device = c.findDevice(req.param('ip'));

    c.open(device, ...);
    c.on('data', function(myData) {
      sails.sockets.broadcast(req.socket.id, 'message', {host: myData});
    });

    return res.ok();
  },

  collectUnsubscribe: function(req, res) {
    if (!res.isSocket) return res.badRequest("I need a websocket! Help!");
    if (!caps[req.socket.id]) return res.badRequest("I can't unsubscribe you unless you actually subscribe first.");

    caps[req.socket.id].removeAllListeners('data');
    delete caps[req.socket.id]; 

    return res.ok();
  }
}
```

Basically, it goes like this: when a browser request triggers `collectSubscribe`, a new `Cap` instance listens to the provided IP. When the browser triggers `collectUnsubscribe`, the server retreives that `Cap` instance, tells it to stop listening, and then deletes it.

**Production Considerations**: please be aware that the list of `Cap`s is NOT PERSISTENT (since it is stored in memory and not a DB)! So if your server is turned off and rebooted (due to lightning storm, etc), the list will be cleared, but considering that all websocket connections will be dropped anyway, I don't see any need to worry about this.

## Old Answer, Kept for Reference

You can use `sails.sockets.join(req, room)` and `sails.sockets.leave(req, room)` to manage socket rooms. Essentially you have a room called "collect", and only sockets joined in that room will receive a `sails.sockets.broadcast(room, eventName, data)`.

More info on how to user `sails.sockets` [here](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets).

In `api/controllers/SomeController.js`:

```
collectSubscribe: function(req, res) {
  if (!res.isSocket) return res.badRequest();

  sails.sockets.join(req, 'collect');
  return res.ok();

},

collectUnsubscribe: function(req, res) {
  if (!res.isSocket) return res.badRequest();

  sails.sockets.leave(req, 'collect');
  return res.ok();
}
```

Finally, we need to tell the server to broadcast messages to our `'collect'` room.
Note that this only need to happen **once**, so you can do this in a file under the `config/` directory.

For this example, I'll put this in `config/sockets.js`

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
};


c.on('data', function(myData) {
  var eventName = 'message';
  var data = {host: myData};
  sails.sockets.broadcast('collect', eventName, data);
});
```

I am assuming that `c` is accessible here; If not, you could define it as `sails.c = ...` to make it globally accessible.

Comment: First of all, thanks for an awesome answer! I have one problem: Currently I have to initialize `c` with a parameter I got from the request `(req.param("ip"))`, and each user needs to be in his own room.
 `c.on('data')` emits new data based on user input

Comment: OK,  wow that is a different end goal than I assumed! If you could edit your question with some of this specific detail, that would help a lot. Also,  I would like to see how `c` is declared, as it now seems more relevant to the question. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I came up with it only after I saw your answer. I updated my question accordingly